# Counting a particular value across multiple columns of data

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

In my dataset I have a simple table that contains `Yes/No` responses in several columns. For example, this can be survey data that logs responses to a bunch of questions, with survey ID and survey date logged.

Example data:

| ID | Date | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10.08.2022 | Yes | No | Yes |
| 2 | 10.08.2022 | Yes | Yes | No |
| 3 | 12.08.2022 | No | No | Yes |
| 4 | 14.08.2022 | Yes | No | No |

Based on this data, I want to know which question was most frequently answered with "Yes". What is the best way of doing this? My end goal is to have a Power BI visual that displays the category/question and the count:

| Category | "Yes" Count |
| --- | --- |
| A | 3 |
| C | 2 |
| B | 1 |

So far I've only managed to do individual columns (using quick measures) but this is not ideal:

```
A Yes = CALCULATE(
COUNTA('Table1'[A]),
'Table1'[A]
    IN { TRUE })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to transform your table into below format using unpivoting :

[image: fgd]

You need to go to the query editor, select [ID] and [Date] columns, then pick unpivot other columns option, like in the picture:

[image: FDFG]

Then You can write this DAX Measure :

```
CountOfYes =
COUNTX ( FILTER ( Table1, Table1[Answer] = "Yes" ), Table1[Answer] )
```

And Finally, Create a table or matrix visual, put [Category] field on the row, and put 'CountOfYes' measure into value field:

If we do it,

[image: FDS]

Comment: This really worked, however short lived, when I realised that for some of the letters (A, C, D) I need to count the "Yes" values and for other letters (B and E) I need to count the "No" values. The "CountOfYes" column would become "Not Compliant" column. Not sure if I should ask another question regarding this.

Comment: @Gotty revise your question and Ozan will help you accordingly...